# Aperture can't see certain files for importing

Tags: permission, aperture

Directory of miscellaneous jpegs that I want to bring into Aperture to keyword and export at web resolutions.

So they are on /Volumes/Bugkiller/temppix

When I go to import them, the directory appears blank.

Permissions:

```
/Volumes/Bugkiller/Temppix
816 ==> ls -ld .
drwxr-xr-x  59 sherwood  staff  2006  9 Jan 20:47 .

-rw-r--r--  1 sherwood  staff   303401 30 Dec 10:03 Ceileidh+Radar.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 sherwood  staff    98669  9 Jan 16:37 LarchInSummer-Big.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 sherwood  staff   176272  9 Jan 16:40 LarchOnLakeInFall.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 sherwood  staff   107908  9 Jan 16:35 Larix-Fall_colour.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 sherwood  staff  1770468  7 Jan 10:13 Manitoba_Maple-male-flowers.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 sherwood  staff  1760805  7 Jan 10:14 Manitoba_Maple-new-leaves.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 sherwood  staff  1291674  7 Jan 10:14 Manitoba_Maple-seeds.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 sherwood  staff   257811 16 Aug 06:55 SB-willmore (1).jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 sherwood  staff   227425 29 Jul 15:27 SB-willmore.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 sherwood  staff   154776  6 Oct 19:01 Unknown_Plant2_1.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 sherwood  staff   176432  6 Oct 19:01 Unknown_Plant2_2.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 sherwood  staff   179114  6 Oct 19:01 Unknown_Plant2_3.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 sherwood  staff   154398  6 Oct 19:01 Unknown_Plant2_4.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 sherwood  staff   330779  6 Oct 19:01 Unknown_Plant2_5.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 sherwood  staff   249686  6 Oct 19:01 Unknown_Plant2_6.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 sherwood  staff   186695  6 Oct 19:01 Unknown_Plant2_7.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 sherwood  staff   332698  6 Oct 19:01 Unknown_Plant2_8.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 sherwood  staff   304529  6 Oct 01:36 Unknown_Plant_1.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 sherwood  staff   313172  6 Oct 01:36 Unknown_Plant_2.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 sherwood  staff   322168  6 Oct 01:36 Unknown_Plant_3.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 sherwood  staff   308523  6 Oct 01:36 Unknown_Plant_4.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 sherwood  staff   410239  6 Oct 01:36 Unknown_Plant_5.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 sherwood  staff   411188  5 Dec 15:19 What flower?.jpg
```

In this directory they are all visible:

```
/Volumes/Bugkiller
819 ==> ls -ld NikonTransfer/
drwxr-xr-x  705 sherwood  staff  23970  3 Jan 16:21 NikonTransfer/
/Volumes/Bugkiller

/Volumes/Bugkiller
821 ==> ls -l NikonTransfer/ | head
total 29007472
-rw-r--r--  1 sherwood  staff  15034112 28 Oct 19:10 2016-10-28_19-10-03.50.JPG
-rw-r--r--  1 sherwood  staff  15080790 28 Oct 19:10 2016-10-28_19-10-55.60.JPG
-rw-r--r--  1 sherwood  staff  11888291 28 Oct 19:11 2016-10-28_19-11-18.30.JPG
-rw-r--r--  1 sherwood  staff  13237397 28 Oct 19:11 2016-10-28_19-11-42.20.JPG
-rw-r--r--  1 sherwood  staff  16067523 29 Oct 14:31 2016-10-29_14-31-38.60.JPG
-rw-r--r--  1 sherwood  staff  15532431 29 Oct 14:32 2016-10-29_14-32-03.40.JPG
-rw-r--r--  1 sherwood  staff  14049542 29 Oct 14:32 2016-10-29_14-32-12.30.JPG
-rw-r--r--  1 sherwood  staff  16522512 29 Oct 14:32 2016-10-29_14-32-27.40.JPG
-rw-r--r--  1 sherwood  staff  16769283 29 Oct 14:32 2016-10-29_14-32-37.70.JPG
```

ls -l@ shows neither the directory nor the files with any extended attributes.

copying a file from NikonTransfer to Temppix, and the new file is not visible.

Navigating to this location in Finder shows the files.

A simple photo browser iSmartPhoto shows the files.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Aperture can't see ".JPG" but can see ".jpg" and ".jpeg". I just went through a similar arduous process, name changing ".JPG" to ".jpg" and then re-importing hundreds of files; Aperture was then able to see them.

Capture 1 Pro8 was able to see both extensions; as I just wasted an hour, this has pushed me over the edge to abandon Aperture forever, which hurts, as I have used it professionally for many years. I recently updated to El Capitan, too, and this squirrelly behaviour re. these extensions started then.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different and thanks for contributing your answer. Can I suggest you submit [feedback](http://www.apple.com/feedback/aperture.html) to the Aperture team about this? That's the only way to get bugs etc resolved.